# Why the slideshow is not shown in my theme?

Tags: theme-development, themes, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am pretty new in WordPress theme developing and I have the following problem.

I am trying to create a WordPress theme that used **BootStrap** CSS framework based on this BootStrap demo static website (I have the entire source of this site because it is a downlodable tutorial): http://www.html.it/guide/img/bootstrap/demo/home.html

This is my **custom WP theme**: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

So I have create a basic WP theme and as first stage I want to insert the **slideshow** of the previous demo page in the **header.php** file of my WP theme, so this is my **header.php** code:

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes(); ?>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type'); ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>" />
<title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?> <?php if ( is_single() ) { ?> » Blog Archive <?php } ?> <?php wp_title(); ?></title>
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress <?php bloginfo('version'); ?>" />
<!-- leave this for stats -->

<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url'); ?>" />

<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- Sezione slider con Flexslider -->
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
     <div id="main-slider" class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-1.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
               </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-2.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
               </p>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li>
           <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/flexslider/flex-3.jpg"/>
           <div class="flex-caption">
               <p class="flex-caption-text">
                   <span>Lorem ipsum</span><br>
                   <span>sit dolor</span><br>
                   <span>adipiscing elitur</span>
           </p>
           </div>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div><!-- /.flexslider -->
    </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->

<center>
<div id="page">
<div id="header">

<h1><a href="<?php echo get_settings('home'); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></h1>
<div class="description"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
</div>
<hr />
```

As you can see I have simply take the  block of the static demo website and I have put it at the beginning of my **header.php** file.

Ok, my WordPress theme is configured to use the BootStrap CSS and the **flexslider.css** and also the **style2.css** file that represent what in the demo website is the **stili-custom.css** (my custom CSS settings that is loaded at last to ovverride the definied properties)

As you can see the problem is that at the beginning of my theme the slide show not appear and I have no idea about this issue.

Why? Can you help me to solve this problem?

UPGRADE 1:

In the **functions.php** I put to load all the JavaScripts:

```
/* Function automatically executed by the hook 'load_java_scripts':
 * 1) Load all my JavaScripts
 */
function load_java_scripts() {
    // Load JQuery:
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    // Load bootstrap.min.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), 'v3.0.3', true);
    // Load FlexSlider JavaScript
    wp_enqueue_script('flexSlider-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1', true);
    // Load FancyBox:
    wp_enqueue_script('fancy-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/plugins/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.pack.js', array('jquery'), 'v2.1.5', true);
    // Load scripts.js:
    wp_enqueue_script('fancy-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scripts.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_java_scripts');
```

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Where are you enqueueing the flexslider **script**?

Comment: @ChipBennett in the functions.php of my theme, I have edit my original post, at the end you can see what I have do